# Importing DXF Polyline scale problem

Tags: import

when I'm importing a dfx (simple floorplan) with a defined measure l/b of 6000 x 4000 mm: how can I make sure, the imported dxf will be the exact length of the original, in case I need Blender only to convert from .dxf to .ply.?

Problem, if imported, the draw of polylines, all closed, will be ~100 times bigger in scale. I tested it with other dxf (im using nanoCAD to export dwg to dxf) but theres the same issue. I cannot get it fixed.

All Settings in Blender are metric and milimeters. The original dxf is in mm too. what can I do?